# How to create a dictionary of lists with unique mentions from a tab-delimited csv file using boolean values

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, boolean

I have a big tab-deltimited csv file: first tab is for emotion words, second for eight basic emotions, plus the values `positive` and `negative`, and the last tab is the boolean value if the the second tab-value fits the first.

A snippet from the file:

```
snarl   anger   1
snarl   anticipation    0
snarl   disgust 1
snarl   fear    0
snarl   joy 0
snarl   negative    1
snarl   positive    0
snarl   sadness 0
snarl   surprise    0
snarl   trust   0
snarling    anger   1
snarling    anticipation    0
snarling    disgust 0
snarling    fear    0
snarling    joy 0
snarling    negative    1
snarling    positive    0
snarling    sadness 0
snarling    surprise    0
snarling    trust   0
```

**My code** so far to do this:

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint
from itertools import groupby

l = list(csv.reader(open('NRC-Emotion-Lexicon-Wordlevel-v0.92.txt')))
f = lambda x: x[-1] #manipulate number to see different results
{k:[tuple(x[0:1]) for x in v] for k,v in groupby(sorted(l[1:], key=f), f)}

pprint(l)
```

**My current output** is not that good looking:

```
['asylum\tanger\t0'],
 ['asylum\tanticipation\t0'],
 ['asylum\tdisgust\t0'],
 ['asylum\tfear\t1'],
 ['asylum\tjoy\t0'],
 ['asylum\tnegative\t1'],
 ['asylum\tpositive\t0'],
 ['asylum\tsadness\t0'],
 ['asylum\tsurprise\t0'],
 ['asylum\ttrust\t0'],
```

**My question is:** How do I create a dictionary of lists with one unique key for each of the repeated emotion words (reducing 10 repetitions to 1, each) and only include the second tab elements in the list of that dictionary key,  when they have the boolean value of 1?

Any kind of help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:** as one of the replies stated, an example of the desired output would look like this:

```
{'snarl': ['anger', 'disgust'], #included in list due to having '1', ignoring 'positve' and 'negative'
 'snarling': ['anger'], #etc...
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

The first and the last lines of the file are empty, as I mentioned in the answers per comments.

Comment: Would you mind giving an example output? Having trouble understanding what you want

Comment: @dheiberg I edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` and update a dictionary of lists while iterating a `csv.reader` object.

Your criterion is added in an `if` statement, taking care to convert the number to an integer via `int`.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO

x = StringIO("""snarl   anger   1
snarl   anticipation    0
...
snarling    surprise    0
snarling    trust   0""")

d = defaultdict(list)

# replace x with open('file.csv', 'r')
with x as fin:
    reader = filter(None, csv.reader(x, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True))
    # or, reader = filter(None, csv.reader(x, delimiter='\t'))
    for word, emotion, num in reader:
        if int(num):
            d[word].append(emotion)
```

Result:

```
print(d)

defaultdict(list,
            {'snarl': ['anger', 'disgust', 'negative'],
             'snarling': ['anger', 'negative']})
```

Comment: I'm getting a `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)` for the line with `for word, emotion, num in reader:`

Comment: @Waldkamel, can't replicate. Have you tried `reader = csv.reader(x, delimiter='\t')`?

Comment: I just noticed that my file is actually a .txt file, but is tab-delimited. Could this cause the problem?

Comment: No, the extension txt / tab delimiting is no problem.

Comment: as I mentioned at the other answers: the first and last lines of the file are empty. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Yep, that's a problem. I've updated my solution. `filter(None, ...)` may help here.

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach. Using `defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
with open(filename) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        if row[2] == '1':
            d[row[0]].append(row[1])
print(d)
```

---

*Edit as per comment*

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
with open(filename) as infile:
    for row in infile:
        if row.strip():
            val = row.split()
            if val[2] == '1':
                d[val[0]].append(val[1])
print(d)
```

Comment: I'm getting `IndexError: list index out of range` for this answer as well. The first and last lines are empty - could this cause the problem?

Comment: Updated ans without `csv` module

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were almost close to the answer. But when you invoked csv.reader, you didn't specify delimiter (which means it defaulted to comma as delimiter)

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l = map(str.split, open('NRC-Emotion-Lexicon-Wordlevel-v0.92.txt').readlines())
>>> f = lambda x: x[1]
>>> {k:set(e[0] for e in v) for k,v in groupby(sorted(filter(bool, l), key=f), f)}
{'anger': {'snarling', 'snarl'}, 'anticipation': {'snarling', 'snarl'}, 'disgust': {'snarling', 'snarl'}, 'fear': {'snarling', 'snarl'}, 'joy': {'snarling', 'snarl'}, 'negative': {'snarling', 'snarl'}, 'positive': {'snarling', 'snarl'}, 'sadness': {'snarling', 'snarl'}, 'surprise': {'snarling', 'snarl'}, 'trust': {'snarling', 'snarl'}}
```

Comment: It's giving me an `IndexError: list index out of range` for the line with `f=lambda x: x[1]`

Comment: @Waldkamel. That means `l` is not a list of list (probably due to the file being not tab separated). Try initializing l as I have mentioned in the last line `l = map(str.split, open('tmp.txt').readlines())`

Comment: I replaced the `l` line with your suggested edit, but it still gives me the same error message, sadly...

Comment: I noticed that the first and last lines of the file are empty. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @Waldkamel Yes.. The empty lines were causing this issue. I have updated my answer with a `filter` statement to get rid of blank lines

Comment: Hm, this gives me now only one key - a basic emotion - and the values are comma-separated emotion words.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it. You could also use `collections.defaultdict` if you wished (instead of `setdefault`):

```
import csv

with open('NRC-Emotion-Lexicon-Wordlevel-v0.92.txt', newline='') as file:
    l = [row[:-1] for row in csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
            if row and row[-1] == '1']  # Not empty and last elem is true.

d = {}
for e_word, basic in l:
    d.setdefault(e_word, []).append(basic)

print('dictionary d:\n', d)
```

Output:

```
dictionary d:
 {'snarl': ['anger', 'disgust', 'negative'], 'snarling': ['anger', 'negative']}
```

Comment: This gives me a `IndexError: list index out of range` - as I mentioned in other comments, the first and last line of the file are empty. That's what's causing the error, right? I edited my question for more clarity.

Comment: Waldkamel: Yes,  that's the problem (I never noticed the comment). The good news is it's trivial to fix—see update I just made.